# Why the outputs of a*a + a*a and a**2 + a**2 is different in Python?

Tags: python, overflow

```
a = 1e200

print(a)
b = a*a + a*a
print(b)

c = a**2 + a**2

print(c)
```

output:

```
1e+200
inf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\TUD\Materials\SPE\Session1\overflowerror.py", line 7, in <module>
    c = a**2 + a**2
        ~^^~
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Why b is inf while c causes a overflow error though they have same value?

I also tried this in C and found that both a*a and pow(a, 2) returned inf without error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    double a = 1e200;

    double b = a*a;

    printf("%f\n", a);
    printf("%f\n", b);
    double c = pow(a, 2) + pow(a, 2);

    printf("%f\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
99999999999999996973312221251036165947450327545502362648241750950346848435554075534196338404706251868027512415973882408182135734368278484639385041047239877871023591066789981811181813306167128854888448.000000
inf
inf
```

Comment: You can simplify it further: Just `b = a*a` and `c = a**2` replicate the issue you've shown (on my 64-bit Linux system at least), no need for the addition as well. The first succeeds with the result `inf`, the second fails with the error shown.

Comment: `a` is `float`, so I guess with `a**2` C function [`float_pow()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/626c414995bad1dab51c7222a6f7bf388255eb9e/Objects/floatobject.c#L841) is called and you see  the result from C `pow()`. With multiplication, the result is simple `inf`

Comment: My guess (and that's all it is) is that [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) was implemented to throw rather than return `inf` even though `*` works differently (after all, one is a function and the other is an operator), and when [`**`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator) was added later, since it uses `pow()`'s semantics, it inherited the behavior.